# Spring Boot Devtools Remote cause error at Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, cloud-foundry, spring-boot-devtools

Sorry, cant post images with low reputation)
Here is my settings:
Spring Boot: 2.3.0.RELEASE

[secret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9worG.png)

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beKaL.png)

[Intellij Idea IDE Run/Debug Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsgiw.png)

I have this app working at Pivotal Cloud Foundry. I have runing Remote App and after build through IDE or using

`./gradlew clean assemble`

I get
`Exception in thread "File Watcher" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected 404 NOT_FOUND response uploading class files`

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPGCF.png)

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to run Dev Tools here? You wouldn't normally do this, and I quote from the docs `Remote support is opt-in as enabling it can be a security risk.`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-devtools-remote. It should also normally be disabled when you deploy to CF with the Java buildpack.

Comment: For development purposes to push code changes to remote and automatically make mods and test them immediately.

Comment: It does not seem like it's able to connect to your app. If you run `cf logs` on your app, do you see any requests to the app? Do you require a proxy to talk to the Internet?

Comment: 2020-07-16T13:51:24.54+0300 [RTR/7] OUT lsb-tired-elephant-pw.cfapps.io - [2020-07-16T10:51:24.525144702Z] "POST /.~~spring-boot!~/restart HTTP/1.1" 404 2264 6745 "-" "Java/12.0.2" "10.10.66.251:55238" "10.10.148.57:61198" x_forwarded_for:"109.251.102.101, 10.10.66.251" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"e4b853b4-e8b5-4814-4084-b7afb7e2947e" response_time:0.020901 gorouter_time:0.000150 app_id:"bbe49967-be62-492f-830f-a40170e0d5af" app_index:"0" x_cf_routererror:"-" x_b3_traceid:"752f82bc4d56f675" x_b3_spanid:"752f82bc4d56f675" x_b3_parentspanid:"-" b3:"752f82bc4d56f675-752f8...

Comment: Can problem be connected to whether I`m using static or dynamical ip address?

Comment: I'm not using proxy

Comment: I was looking at this a bit and what worked for me was just changing `developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'` to `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'`. I saw the note you must have seen about adding `classpath configurations.developmentOnly`, which seems like it should work but it was unclear to me why you'd want to declare something you need running in production, dev tools in this case, as `developmentOnly` and then mess with the classpath to make it work. It seems less roundabout to just change it to `implementation` which worked.

Comment: At any rate, you're getting 404s for that post request because the required dependency is missing. You should be able to confirm by running `unzip -l build/libs/your-app.jar | grep -i dev`, and you should see something like `   223156  07-16-2020 13:17   BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-devtools-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar` included in the JAR (your version may vary). If it's missing, then the library isn't being included and that's why you're getting the 404.

Comment: I got `223155  2020-06-28 20:36   BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-devtools-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar`

Comment: just `implementation` same result

Comment: What do you see in `cf logs` for the remote app output when you save a change and it generates the error you posted in your question? Also, set `logging.level.org.springframework.boot.devtools=debug` on the remote app. You should minimally see ` o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter      : Creating new Restarter for thread Thread[main,5,main]` to indicate devtools are running.

Comment: yes,  `main] o.s.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter : Creating new Restarter for thread Thread[main,5,main]` presents in logs

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing what it could be based on the info here. If you've got a sample app you can point me to that replicates the problem, I'd be happy to take a look and see if I can spot the issue. Maybe someone else has some ideas or things I've overlooked.

Comment: @DanielMikusa please check your linkedin(sent invite), I will supply any info I have)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after looking through your demo app I believe the issue is that you're using Spring Webflux and that's not supported at the moment.

The remote devtools functionality is only available with Spring WebMVC & Servlet. See this Github issue for reference: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13092#issuecomment-387350811